# How can i populate a listbox in a selected combobox in vfp?

Tags: combobox, listbox, visual-foxpro, foxpro

For example, combobox had data of categories in table1, and i want to populate the listbox from the second table with subcategory where categories = combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence (?), I just answered a similar question. This code is from that answer, modified slightly to use Northwind sample database's Categories and Products (subcategory for you) tables:

```
Public oForm
oForm = Createobject('SampleForm')
oForm.Show()


Define Class SampleForm As Form
    Height = 800
    Width=600
    DataSession = 2
    Add Object cmbCategories As ComboBox With Top=10, Left=10, Width=250
    Add Object lstProducts As ListBox With Top=10, Left=280, Height=780, Width=310

    Procedure Init
        With This.cmbCategories
            .RowSourceType = 3 && -SQL
            .RowSource = "select CategoryName, CategoryId from ('"+;
                _Samples+;
                "Northwind\Categories') into cursor crsCategories nofilter"
            .ListIndex=1
        Endwith
        With This.lstProducts
            .RowSourceType = 3 && -SQL
            .RowSource = "select ProductName, ProductId from ('"+;
                _Samples+;
                "Northwind\Products') p"+;
                " where p.CategoryId = crsCategories.CategoryId"+;
                " into cursor crsProducts nofilter"
        Endwith
    Endproc

    Procedure cmbCategories.InteractiveChange
        With Thisform.lstProducts
            .ListIndex = 0
            .Requery()
        Endwith
    Endproc
Enddefine
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.